# Is that possible to add a custom button and UI component to file browse dialog in MFC or in win32?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, mfc

I am trying to create a file browse dialog in my windows project. When user was trying to save the file, he can save the file on local or on his cloud account.
For example, when user click save, by using `CFileDialog`, we can open a file dialog like:
[image]

When user wants to save his file to his cloud account, he can click the button which beside "New folder" on the top of this dialog, then this dialog will display the folder organization on the cloud account:
[image]

So I want to ask that is this kind of dialog possible in MFC ? I was searching it for several hours, but I think none of SHBrowseForFolder or `CFileDialog` can satisfy it.
I need to key component:
1, we can add customized button on the top, like the "cloud" button.
2, the content layout or style in the middle can be customized.
Is this kind of UI possible in MFC ?

Comment: I believe you can't customize the default `savefiledialog`, you would need to create an entirely new window.

Comment: What you propably want is a [shell namespace extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095(v=vs.85).aspx). I think you can't add button to the top button bar (not while the user is outside of your namespace) but you could add the root of your namespace extension to the list of places by calling [`CFileDialog::AddPlace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256232(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: @zett42 If I am not wrong this will just add a folder available to the user. He can't change the layout of the filedialog this way.

Comment: @DimChtz Not just an existing folder. A namespace extension is a virtual folder who's content can be displayed in any possible way.

Comment: @zett42 Okay, sorry I was wrong.

Comment: There is a lot of flexibility with `CFileDialog`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class

Comment: Also I suggest to [search OldNewThing for "namespace extension"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?rq=site%3Ablogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Foldnewthing&rn=oldnewthing&ral=1&query=namespace+extension), which is one of the most valuable resources for this kind of thing.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I read this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class , I totally don't understand how to use the content in this link to customize the dialog to the UI I need. I want to change the layout, the color, the icon, can you point out which function in the link can achive that effects please ?

Comment: @zett42 it seems namespace extension can work, I am reading it, thanks!

Comment: @zett42 by using namespace extension, can I change the icon of files and the colors or the theme of it? For example, the theme color is green, the icon before folder is different with windows folder icon like in my example pictures above.

Comment: You can define your own icons for the folders by providing the [IExtractIcon interface from IShellFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093(v=vs.85).aspx#optional). For the folder view, you could use a [custom draw list view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569(v=vs.85).aspx#list_tree) or create your own control from scratch to control everything.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks! Is that possible to change the existing CFileDialog class as IShellFolder easily? The reason why I ask this is our current windows app can only save file to the local. Now we want to add a function" save to cloud". The easiest UI change seems is to add a "cloud" button in the file browse dialog when the user save the file. If I use IShellFolder as you said, we need abandon the existing file browse dialog , correct ? Our exsiting dialog is using CFileDialog.

Comment: This works differently. You register a shell extension which will then be visible in any file dialog and also in explorer. I believe you can restrict it to be visible only in your own process. You have to look at the reference and examples, I personally don't have much experience implementing shell extension. That's why I only write this as comments.

Comment: Exactly! Just like in the windows 8, when the user wants to save the document to his google cloud account, he can use this similar dialog to save it.

Comment: Correct. Because the cloud storage is implemented as a shell namespace extension. You are asking about customizing the shell save dialog (which *is* possible as well), when you should have asked about extending the shell. Clearly an XY problem.